# Does a tool exist that can tell me if a line of code using the C++ stdlib requires a version higher than version X?

Tags: c++, clang++, specifications

I've been dealing with a project where we need to determine how much of the code requires C++11 and new features. I've been able to achieve part of that by using Clang and diagnostic flags "-Wc++98-compat-pedantic -Wc++11-compat-pedantic -Wc++14-compat-pedantic -Wc++17-compat-pedantic". That's given me a good idea of language feature usage in the code I am examining.

But something missing from that is C++ standard library features. Is there a way to get similar data? I'd settle for just getting everything beyond a specific version and going from there.

Comment: I don't understand the question. It seems to me that the flags you mentioned do what you want. How does "using stdlib" makes any difference?

Comment: I think there isn't any real substitute for simply compiling the program with the compiler that you want to make sure it compiles on, and then observing what compile-errors you get (and ideally, fixing them).

Comment: Usually going forward should not cause much problem because most changes to the language maintain backward compatibility... So unless you have have binary dependencies to an older version, you should use at least c++17 these days.

Comment: If I'm using C++14, I don't use C++17 features.  If I have code that depends on C++14, and can't be compiled with an earlier compiler I use a `#if __cplusplus < 201402L` `#error C++14 or higher` `#endif` in the file, which is redundant in that the compiler will fail due to the unsupported C++14-isms.  I only do it because I reckon its easier for the maintenance person (who may be my future self) to see the immediate problem.

Comment: @Eljay The issue is that my project needs to comply with some industry-specific coding standards which are based on older versions of the C++ spec than the code was written for. I need to understand the effort required to go to a previous C++ spec version and the build-break-fix approach doesn't enable understanding the effort required so I can target a specific coding standard.

Comment: @bolov Check out https://en.cppreference.com/w/. There are a number of objects that get added to the standard library with each new version of the C++ standard like unique_ptr. I need a way to count the use of objects like this so I can understand the effort needed to port code to an older C++ spec version. The reason for doing this is in a separate comment I made.

Comment: @Phil1970 The problem is indeed going backward. It's not a binary compatibility thing though. It involves complying with certain requirements that are industry specific and those requirements are based on earlier versions of the C++ spec. There is some choice in what set of requirements the project conforms to but I need to understand how painful the various options will be to go back to a specific spec then make the project conform to the rest of the requirements.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think it is possible without compiling for that specific version and even then if you have many problems in header files, it might take a lot of time to evaluate as reported errors can multiplies... Then not all features are easy to port back as many features are there to make the life easier. Probably the easier way to evaluate would be to take a whole day to fix errors (or comment code) and evaluate the percentage that you were able to do. And you have to take into account that you might introduce bugs doing that. Find in file might also be useful once you know some cases.

Comment: @Matt **(1)** You can easily know the minimum standard required to compile your code.  **(2)** You can easily know if you have a lot of errors or only a fews by going back one version at a time (and take maybe up to one hour to fix main problems). **(3)** You know which standard you target.  **Unless you update your compiler recently or that your teams is mostly writting old style C++ code, you probably don't want to go back more than one version** after you found the first version that do not compile (unless you can easily fixes them). Even then it is very risky that good developpers leave...

Comment: @phil1970 example: existing code written to C++14 is being considered to conform to the MISRA C++ 2008 coding standard which is based on C++ 2003. So to determine the effort for this means 1) determining the effort to go back to C++2003 and 2) determining the effort to resolve MISRA violations. There are plenty of tools to determine #2, but nothing comprehensive for determining #1. Sometimes you need numbers to prove how bad an idea is. This is one such case.

Answer (score 0):

I did eventually find a good enough solution. The Clang diagnostic flag `-Wc++98-compat-pedantic` was the key to producing the data about the source I needed.

I needed to effectively change the compiler to clang and use this diagnostic flag, capture the output and parse it. Then I had data about the amount of code that relied on language features introduced with each revision of the C++ specification.

One major shortcoming is an inability to examine standard library usage and check against the language version that introduced them. But for just getting an idea about how painful it would be to make a piece of code conform to a specific old C++ spec version, this was sufficient.